# Remove rows from Pandas DataFrame based on index condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                    0           1           2           3           4
19238V105         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
91731X102         NaN         NaN         NaN   2450900.0    996600.0   
97X1              NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I would like to drop all of the rows where: `len(index) != 9`.  So the result would be:

```
                    0           1           2           3           4
19238V105         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
91731X102         NaN         NaN         NaN   2450900.0    996600.0
```

EDIT

I wrote this code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(index) != 9:
        df = df.drop(index)
```

Is there a better way?  Also, I'm not entirely sure why both the `index, row` are required and not just `index`.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df.index.str.len() >= 9]
```

Comment: I modified this to `== 9`, but yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thank you